# Restify on Cloudfoundry 'invalid ELF header'

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, restify

I'm deploying a node.js app to Cloudfoundry, the only module dependency is restify. I've tried pushing it with my local node_modules directory and also using npm shrinkwrap and 'ignoreModules' in cloudfoundry.json but always end up with this in the stdout.log:

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: '/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/myapp-0-6f9cf62f9bbe58f5d2eb13a94acb5d3a/app/node_modules/restify/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings.node: invalid ELF header' }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: sorry i mean 'ignore**Node**Modules'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the module is compiled for your local architecture (say x86), and the server trying to run it is a different architecture (say 64 bit). Node modules can have C++ extensions in them that npm will handle building, you can't necessarily just move the binaries in the node_modules folder from one platform to another, you need to recompile them.

I don't know enough about Cloudfoundry to tell you how to do that though, hopefully someone else has a better answer.

Comment: That was my first thought when i saw 'invalid ELF header' but then i used npm shrinkwrap and ignoreModules to avoid uploading my local binaries but got the same error.

Comment: Can you try pushing it without the node_modules folder to make sure it isn't still trying to use your locally compiled version instead of using ignoreModules?

Comment: Excellent, thx! Turns out i had to actually delete the node_modules folder as well, i figured a cloudfoundry.json with {'"ignoreNodeModules":true'} was enough to ignore the local binaries :S

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue setting up a dev Docker environment. I wanted to mount my source files on the docker image, but have a node_modules directory compiled just for the docker image. When I made a new directory on the docker image, `npm install` in that directory, and then used soft links for some of my source code I saw the same behavior.

Solution: don't use soft links.